# Golang: how to send signal and stop sending values to a goroutine

Tags: go, channel

I am new to go and I am trying to learn some basic use of signal functions in goroutines. I have an infinite for loop in go. Through this for loop, I pass values to a goroutine through a channel. **I also have a threshold value after which I will like to stop sending values indefinitely to the goroutine** (i.e. close the channel). **When the threshold value is reached, I will like to break the for loop.** Following is what I have tried so far.

In this particular example, `thresholdValue = 10` and I would like to print values from `0 , ..., 9` and then stop.

I followed [this post on medium](https://medium.com/@matryer/golang-advent-calendar-day-two-starting-and-stopping-things-with-a-signal-channel-f5048161018) and [this post on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37729643/golang-how-can-i-stop-the-execution-of-a-for-loop-from-outside-the-loop). I picked elements from these posts which I could use.

This is what I have done at the present. **In the main function of my code, I purposefully make the for loop an infinite loop. My main intention is to learn how to have the goroutine `readValues()` take the threshold value and then stop transmission of values indefinitely in the channel.**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
        ch := make(chan int)
        quitCh := make(chan struct{}) // signal channel
        thresholdValue := 10 //I want to stop the incoming data to readValues() after this value 

        go readValues(ch, quitCh, thresholdValue)
       

    for i:=0; ; i++{
        ch <- i
    }
    
}

func readValues(ch chan int, quitCh chan struct{}, thresholdValue int) {
    for value := range ch {
        fmt.Println(value)
        if (value == thresholdValue){
            close(quitCh)
        }
    }
}
```

The goroutine in my code still misses the threshold. I will appreciate any direction as to how I should proceed from here.

Comment: `for i:=0; i<thresholdValue; i++{`

Comment: using this `for i:=0; ; i++{`, if you stop reading `ch` (exit from readValues) the program deadlocks.

Comment: I repeat (because upvotes i dont understand) if you exit from readValues, stop reading ch, the program deadlocks. A program that deadlocks is good for garbage.

Comment: though you can still add an if statement within readValues to not process values lower than threshold....

Comment: what you want answer is not `how to exit from readValues` but `how to stop sending values indefinitely`

Comment: mh-cbon: Thanks for your suggestions. I will like to add an if statement within readValues to not process values beyond threshold. Yes, I will like to `stop sending values indefinitely`. How can I do that? I have updated the question.

Comment: `for i:=0; i<thresholdValue; i++{ ch <-i }; close(ch)`

Comment: there is no such thing like real infinity (in computer). There is always a stop condition otherwise this is a mad machine (though i have no doubt humans can do that kind of thing).

Comment: @ConfusedScientist I'm not sure I understand exactly what you're looking for but maybe this could help: https://play.golang.org/p/qs-4UyX9_JX

Comment: you close `quitCh` but since `main` does not read from it, that closure means nothing.  @mkopriva's example uses a value passed on that channel to indicuate to `main` that `readValues` is done processing.

Comment: mkopriva:  The code that you wrote is very close to what I would like. Would you like to put that as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to show good faith, this is the program rewritten.

```golang
package main

import (
    "log"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    ch := make(chan int, 5) // capacity increased for demonstration
    thresholdValue := 10

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        readValues(ch)
        wg.Done()
    }()

    for i := 0; i < thresholdValue; i++ {
        ch <- i
    }
    close(ch)
    log.Println("sending done.")
    wg.Wait()

}

func readValues(ch chan int) {
    for value := range ch {
        <-time.After(time.Second) // for demonstratin purposes.
        log.Println(value)
    }
}
```

In this version `readValues` exits ***because*** the `for` loop did exit and that `main` closed `ch`.

In other words a stop condition take effects and triggers the exit sequence (signal `end of input` then wait for the processing to finish)

Comment: I read the original question to mean that the `main` function produces the values but the `readValues` function knows when the processing is complete.  Your example assumes the `main` function knows when the processing is complete.  Since there's no non-academic goal to the question it's hard to argue that `main` could be made to know when the threshold was met.

Comment: @DanielFarrell having the consumer to decide when to stop processing (ie: its caller) is a design error. By the tme the consumer has sent out the signal to the caller the process should stop, mre items have accumulated, but they wont get treated as the consumer has decided to stop before its producer. It is taking the problem upside down. The results of such design are more complex code, more monkeypatching, more troubles. There is a way to write concurrency that helps you to prevent a whole class of bugs.

Comment: can't disagree with that.  +1